Cognito Auth URL differences / endpoints
Im currently in the process of implementing authentication in Next.js using Cognito. While exploring the documentation, I encountered two different URLs for authentication purposes. One is this authentication URL:
https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{my-pool-id}
However, I also noticed the existence of a token endpoint:
https://{your-custom-domain}.auth.{region}.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize
I'm a bit confused, when i should use one or another? is there a recommended path? the AWS docs are not really helping.
Cognito documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html"
Thanks!
EDIT: i was thinking that was to refresh the token, but i can also refresh the token using the first URL with a different body payload
